# Can an application be partially cloud-based?

Tags: cloud, storage, wunderlist

This is to do with cloud computing. Wunderlist, for respondents who aren't aware, is supposedly a cloud-based to-do list app. Having checked the docs, I understand that the program generates REST calls to the server with the JSON data format.

Because it's cloud-based, it means that consistency can be achieved across multiple devices (handy if you want the same list on your phone and computer).

My question is: given that you have the front-end that says how the app looks and the back-end saying how the app retrieves data from Wunderlist's server, what happens if you don't have an internet connection? Would that mean you'd have to write the app so that it can do both local AND cloud storage, or just the cloud?

If it's a hybrid of the two, then is it really a complete cloud-based application or only a partially cloud-based application?

Many thanks to anyone who can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach, if you want the app to be abel to run when there is no internet connection, is to have a copy of the data locally and synch with the server or 'cloud' either whenever there is a change on either side or at regular intervals whenever connectivity is available.

This means that you will be 'out of synch' temporarily when not connected to the internet but for many applications that is not a big issue (I suspect a to do list would be included in that set).

Comment: But then there's no real advantage in terms of space versus an app that's solely local, is there? Because both kinds would still need to store the data locally?

Comment: You can 'tune' or design it whatever way you want - for a todo list having consistency across apps may be more important than storage. For a photo storage app, only keeping recent or frequently viewed photos locally and storing all others on the cloud will ensure real local storage savings.